# Java - Trouble Using Audio Clips

Tags: java, audio, wav

I have been searching on youtube for tutorials for how to add sound in java, and they all seem to do the same thing, but that is not working form me:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class main extends JFrame{

public main(){
    super("hi");
    setSize(480, 360);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    main Main = new main();

    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(main.class.getResource("original.wav"));
    clip.play();
}
}
```

When I try to run this it gives me a null pointer exception on the line where I initialize clip. I suspect this is because I have the wrong file url. for clarification, the file is located in the project folder.

I also tried:
    AudioClip clip = null;
        URL url = null;

```
    try {
        url = new URL("original.wav");
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    clip.play();
```

but that did not work either. It gave me a MalformedURLException

Comment: main.class.getResource("original.wav") is null ofcourse. are you sure its in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is I use the javax.sound.sampled libraries.  This is the code I use to load a clip -

```
public Clip loadClip( String filename )
{
    Clip clip = null;

    try
    {
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( getClass().getResource( filename ) );
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open( audioIn );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clip;
}
```

You implement it like this.

```
Clip sound = loadClip( "/sound.wav" );
```

Where you put the sound in a source file "res".  I use a seperate function to play the clips -

```
public void playClip( Clip clip )
{
    if( clip.isRunning() )
    {
        clip.stop();
    }
    clip.setFramePosition( 0 );
    clip.start();
}
```

I generally put this in an Art class, so you might call it like

```
Art.playClip( Art.sound );
```

I hope this helps you!